# Back to correct view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I have three view controllers `A`, `B` and `C`.

`C` is the target.

From `A`, I have a segue named `showCFromA` to view controller `C`.

From `B`, I have another segue named `showCFromB` to view controller `C`.

Now, when `C` is displayed (shown from `B`), I tap on the "Back" button, but at this stage, it shows `A`, and not `B` as I expected.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Are you using a navigation controller and push segues?

Comment: @user3386109 I think we can assume that, yes (due to the mention of the "default Back button").

Answer (score 1):

Don't mess with Back - it makes for a disjointed app experience. You end up at a place you don't expect to be and navigation just doesn't feel right.

If you have a B on the stack, you can just

```
popToViewController:animated:
```

to return to the specific view controller (B) that you want to see.

If you have gone from A directly to C with no intervening stop at B, you can't go there with back. Instead you should just push a B.

If your B *should* be on the stack - i.e. you went from B to C - then B is where you should end up if you simply go back. If that is currently not the case you need to post some more details to help diagnose the problem.

What is confusing right now is what you actually have on the stack. You mention being at A and going to C, then being at B and going to C, but the order in which you do this (and if these are two separate cases) affects the outcome.

Comment: I mean I have A, B, and C. C is the final destination. From A I can go to B (segue named showBfromA). From B I can go to C (segue named showCfromB). However, from A I can also go directly to C (segue named showCfromA). Now I'm standing B and go to C. After that, I tap on Back then I shows A not B @@

Comment: Can you add some code? It would be good to see just what methods are used to push these view controllers and how they cause themselves to be popped. Your description seems like B should be showing after one Back navigation, if you most recently were on B and then pushed C.

Comment: My bad, it is the issue in handling navigation stack

Answer (score 0):

After checking the source again, I found the issue is not properly handling navigation vc stack. When push new VC from B, when viewWillDisapper is called (B), I added "popViewController". Therefore, navigation view controller array has count of 2 (the middle element is removed). This makes strange behavior: From view controller C, I cannot go back.

Comment: @GuillaumeAlgis No they shouldn't edit there original post. Questions should contain the solution as well that is the purpose of the answers, and if this is what he did to solve this then this is an answer. Even if it is worded badly.

Comment: @Popeye Yes, I agree 100%. I read the answer too fast, and due to the wording I thought the problem was not fixed ("From view controller C, I cannot go back").

Comment: Oh ok that makes sense then. It is very badly worded I had to read a couple of times and really think about what they were saying.